# Run Armv8 codes in M1 chip

Tags: c, assembly, arm, apple-silicon, apple-m1

Recently apple released M1 chip, As you know this chip is based on ARM. I want to buy MacBookAir10,1  and have 2 questions:

1. Can I build a/an c/assembly program(for Armv8/Armv7) and run it on M1?
2. Can I create my custom GNU/Linux based on arm and install it on mac?

Comment: The Apple M1 does not support the AArch32 execution state and cannot run ARM32 code.

Comment: I'm sure someone will get Linux running on it eventually, but it doesn't sound like it's in a a state where that can happen. Apple isn't very open.

Comment: @ThomasJager: It might be possible to run GNU/Linux in a VM, which potentially avoids the issue of needing Linux drivers for the real hardware (including graphics which IIRC is one of the main showstoppers, and probably laptop power-management / screen brightness stuff).  But yeah, from the little I've read, running GNU/Linux on bare metal is not happening any time soon, except maybe headless. Possibly with some basic compat-mode graphics but maybe not even that.

Comment: Also, probably we should merge [m1] and [apple-silicon] tags, making one a synonym of the other.  Relevant discussion on apple.SE meta: [M1 tag versus Apple Silicon tag](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3975) also mostly applies to SO.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have instaled iOS and iPadOS apps on my MacBook Pro 13 with M1 chip and it runs perfectly. I think this is without any problems.
2. I heard this is possible, but I can't confirm. I still waiting for Parallels update for M1.

Comment: Note that iOS applications are ARM64 applications, not ARM32 applications as OP wants to run.